# GitHub Flow and Releases

Tags: git, github, git-flow

We are relatively new to git in general. We've been using it for about 6 months and have used GitHub and BitBucket. We've tried to learn as much as is possible by using GitBash so we can get under the core of git.

We're at the stage where we really want to consider our branching strategy and hence I've been doing some research.

In my opinion, GitFlow is overly complicated for our requirements. We work on perhaps 20 different projects in total, and each project may only have releases every 2 months or so. Having looked at GitHub Flow, this seems a pretty straight forward option that would meet our needs - however it does seem to have a flaw that I'd like peoples opinions on.

Anything in the master branch is deployable. We deploy to UAT/QA environments, where that release may remain for 3-4 weeks, depending on how long it takes the client and/or us to sign everything off. In the meantime, someone else may need to work on something completely different. At this stage, based on Github Flow's flow, if that user took a branch from Master they would include the changes that actually at this point in time are still in the QA environment. So, is it that I have misunderstood the first point of GitHub Flow - i.e. anything in the master branch is deployable - does that perhaps only ring true if the code has been through QA etc?

If that's the case, does the flow actually look more like?:

- Take a branch from Master
- Commit changes in branch (only back to branch at this stage)
- Merge branch with a separate branch called "Develop"
- Release to QA/UAT
- When Release is approved, merge branch with Master and deploy?

I think it's specifically Point 1 in GitHub Flow that is confusing us - we surely shouldn't push back to Master when the release is still in QA - that would make the Master branch potentially unstable and certainly not what is currently in Production.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I'm seeing on the [`git-flow` cheat sheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) and [Driessen's original model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), you've got a few things wrong.

While I haven't used the `git-flow` workflow myself, from what I can tell, `master` only gets merged to when the release is ready, and NOT before. This way, `master` *always* reflects what's in Prod - `develop` is what serves as the "main" development branch from which feature branches are pulled and merged. So, a successful `git-flow` workflow looks something like this (assuming all of these branches exist beforehand unless mentioned otherwise):

1. Create a feature branch (which we'll call `topic`) from `develop`
2. Work on `topic` for a while
3. Merge `topic` back into `develop`
4. Do this a few more times until you're ready for release
5. Create a new branch, `QA-releaseno`, from `develop`
6. Do QA/UAT on `QA-releaseno`, committing bugfixes as necessary (you can also merge `QA-releaseno` back into `develop` as many times as you please)
7. When you're ready to release, merge `QA-releaseno` into both `master` and `develop`, tag a release on `master`, and delete `QA-releaseno`

Additionally, what you seem to have done is to conflate `git-flow` and [Chacon's GitHub flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html). GitHub flow, at least in its simplest form, works like this:

1. Spin off a new topic branch (here called `topic`) from `master`
2. Work on `topic` (if you're working on it for a long time, merging `master` back into it periodically is a good idea)
3. Do QA on `topic`
4. Put out a pull request (PR) from `topic` to `master`
5. Once the PR has been code-reviewed to everyone's satisfcation, merge `topic` back to `master`
6. Release `master` immediately, or at least decently quickly

This workflow is designed for teams and organizations that are on a fast release cycle (multiple times per week). QA is done not at the application level, but at the level of an individual feature, task, or ticket. Because the release cycle has immediate (or at least fast) feedback, `master` will always reflect what's in production.

Comment: Are you not referring to GitFlow there, as opposed to GitHub Flow? http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Comment: @dotdev: Looks to me like OP's managed to confuse `git-flow` and GitHub flow, hence his confusion. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I think it sounds like ive confused the two because i have introduced the concept of having a "Development" branch, which could just as easily be called "DevReleases". The reaosn I introduced this into GitHub Flow is because if we want to deploy to QA (using TeamCity and Octopus), ideally we dont want to be updating TeamCity every time to look at the new feature branch i.e. it would be far easier if QA releases were always from the "Development" branch.

Comment: @dotdev: so, what you're looking at is sort of a hybrid workflow, which is neither `git-flow` or GitHub flow - correct? There's certainly nothing wrong with that, but recommending a specific flow is out-of-scope for an SO answer (as it would be primarily opinion-based).

Comment: Thanks for all your input. If having a Release branch just for QA releases is deviating from GitHub Flow then I suppose you're right, it is a hybrid.  I suppose I was looking to clarify whilst also trying to ascertain what the potential risks of this flow are. We have ourselves highlighted that potentially branch1 and branch2 could be merged into the Releases branch almost accidentally, therefore the QA tests might have tested and approved both branches together, but neither branch1 or branch2 in isolation.